# Laravel BelongsTo Relation Existance

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the current relationship between a client and his projects

Project Model

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Client', 'cid');
}
```

Project Controller

```
public function index() {
    $projects = Project::with('client')->orderBy('pid', 'desc')->get();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('projects.index')->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

Now it all works fine, and I am able to get all the information about the client from the project view. However, if the clients id does not exist in the database (in the client table), I get an error "Trying to get property of non-object." Instead of getting this error I want to be able to send an empty object. Not really sure where to start though, do I check from the Model itself or from the Controller or do I add a check in the view?

Comment: If i use ::has instead of ::with for the client, it just omits the entire project row (I'm displaying projects in a table). I want it to still display the project just with an empty contact or an "Unknown" if not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [apply constraint to eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). For a proof of concept,

```
$users = Project::with(array('client' => function($query)
{
  $query->raw(
   /*Add your constraint here to coalesce a default for cid or clients.
     You may set a default null record in the client table for this case.*/
  );

}))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet, when you render a table you use somethink like:

```
project.client.name
```

In this case it should throw an exception because client doesn't exist but you trying to access name property. You should check if client exists when you render this table.

Comment: Yes I do, and that's exactly what I am trying to ask, how exactly do i check if that client exists or not? There are many projects that are being loaded, however, if the client does not exist in the client table, I want it to send an empty object so when I try to grab $projects->client->name it returns a null value from an empty object not an error as no object is found.

Comment: Try this in your code
{{ isset($project.client) ? $project.client : 'Default' }}